Counting number of permutations of a certain order in $S_n$
I am trying to count the number of permutations of order $6$ in $S_8$. I think I am making a mistake somewhere here and I want to know where.
There are $3$ different cycle types with order $6$ in $S_8$: $2$-$3$, $6$, and $6$-$2$ cycles. There are $\dfrac{8 \choose 5}{2 \times 3}$ different $2$-$3$ cycles, taking into account the two ways the $2$-cycle can be written and $3$ ways to write the $3$-cycle. There are $\dfrac{8 \choose 6}{6}$ different $6$ cycles, taking into account the $6$ ways to write the $6$-cycle. There are $\dfrac{8!}{12}$ $6$-$2$ cycles using the same reasoning.

Shouldn't the count for 2-3 be $\binom85\binom52\times 2$?

Why the 5 choose 2?

Think how you construct a 2-3. You shortlist 5 numbers from the list $1,\ldots,8$ then you further choose 2 numbers from the shortlisted for the $2$-cycle and the remaining three automatically form a $3$-cycle (in two different ways).

Your counting of $6$ cycles is also wrong. Imagine you have shortlisted $1,2,\ldots, 6$. How many $6$ cycles can you create? I can create $5!$ of them. So the count of $6$ cycles should be $\binom{8}{6}, 5!$ in total.

What about the cycle types 223 and 233?

The number of permutations of $S_n$ of type $\lambda = \lambda_1^{m_1} \, \cdots \, \lambda_k^{m_k}$, consisting of $m_i$ cycles of length $\lambda_i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq k$ is given by the formula
$$
C_\lambda = \frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^k \lambda_i^{m_i}\,m_i!}
$$
There's a good, brief proof here.
Since the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of the lengths of its cycles, the valid cycle types and their counts are
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda & d_\lambda & C_\lambda \\
\hline 
(6, 2) & 6 \cdot 2 & 3360 \\
(6, 1, 1) & 6 \cdot 1 \cdot 2! & 3360 \\
(3, 3, 2) & 3^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2! & 1120 \\
(3, 2, 2, 1) & 3 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2! & 1680 \\
(3, 2, 1, 1, 1) & 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 3! & 1120
\end{array}
$$
The total number of elements is $10640$.
